# Elasticsearch fuzzy intersection of two arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, fuzzy-search

I have an object in the Elasticsearch index that has a nested object which is a list of strings. 
I would like to do the intersection against this list in both exact and fuzzy ways.
So for example I have browser names with versions in the index like:

```
{
  "browsers": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome 38"
    },
    {
      "name": "Firefox 32"
    },
    {
      "name": "Safari 5"
    }
  ]
}
```

the request could be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Chrome 38"
  },
  {
    "name": "IE 10"
  }
]
```

then I have just 1 exact match.

or another example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Chrome 39"
  },
  {
    "name": "Firefox 33"
  },
  {
    "name": "Safari 5"
  }
]
```

here I have 2 fuzzy-matches(Levenstein=2) and 1 exact match

How would you write this kind of query?

Comment: And what would you expect from a query looking for `{"name": "IE 38"}`? Meaning do you want to match the browser name only, do you want to match the version only? There is no "IE 38" but there is a "Chrome 38", would that match?

Comment: Browser name is essential and the version can change. Also the order doesn't matter. Basically I need some kind of set intersection but the one that would take fuzziness into account.

Comment: How do you store those documents in ES? Can you provide the mapping for the index?